# Error when using Clojure to recursively determine coefficient in Pascal's triangle

Tags: java, exception, recursion, clojure

I'm having some difficulty getting the hang of recursion in Clojure. In this example, the function works correctly when `j == 0` or `j == i`, but in all other cases, when the recursive calls will be made, I am getting a `"ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn"` exception. This error pops up before anything else is displayed to output as soon as the program is run.

What can you see in my code that might be causing this problem?

```
(defn pascal [i j]
  (if (== j 0) 1
  (if (== j i) 1
  (+ (pascal (- i 1) (- j 1)) (pascal (- i 1) (j)))))
)

(pascal 4 2)
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: this is the culprit `(j)`

Comment: I've voted to re-open, as there is another problem lurking underneath: the recursion is ill-founded, giving stack overflow.